# MBProgressHUD with Blur effect gives a Thread 1: SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, sigabrt, mbprogresshud

Im using MBProgressHUD with blur effect in one of my projects from [Github](https://github.com/elbryan/MBProgressHUD) , but I cannot get this work.

My code:

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
HUD.blurBackground = YES;
HUD.delegate = self;
HUD.labelText = @"Retrieving data";
HUD.minSize = CGSizeMake(135.f, 135.f);

[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myMixedTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

My Xcode shows a Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT error when im adding the HUD.blurBackground = YES; to the MBProgressHUD. If I delete this line than it works just fine.

My logfile shows the following error:

> [MBProgressHUD setBlurBackground:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x111c06740
>
> 2014-01-22 10:02:15.025 [564:70b] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[MBProgressHUD setBlurBackground:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x111c06740'

Im pretty new to Objective-C and trying to find this out for more than 4 hours now but im getting kind a desperate so I was hoping that someone could help me with this.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Br,

Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clean your project. You've replaced previous version of `MBProgressHUD` with new one but now you need to recompile the project from scratch otherwise your app thinks you're still using the old version

Comment: i tell you HOW I did that. I'm not telling you that you forgot to include them. Really, it doesn't crash for me anymore. You know what? Try implementing setter yourself. I guess it might work for you

Comment: or just make clean. it's a wild guess, but it also might work

Comment: Adnrey, thank you for your answer, Am I overlooking here something maybe?

Comment: @Jan sorry, didn't get you

Comment: [MBProgressHUD setBlurBackground:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: did you try cleaning your project? implementing setter manually?

Comment: How can I do this? Thank you for your help

Comment: to clean project in Xcode press Product->Clean. to implement setter manually add this method to MBProgressHUD.m: - (void)setBlurBackground:(BOOL)blurBackground{ _blurBackground = blurBackground }, comment @synthesize blurBackground and make this property nonatomic

Comment: what exactly helped you?

Comment: Ah, sorry. It works only in the simulator and not on device (iPhone 5s) I only clean the project, im trying to add the following now to to the MBProgressHUD.m

Comment: clean it with the device selected - it will help. this is the issue. you've probably changed version of MBProgressHUD, right?

Comment: Thanks a million :) It worked by cleaning. Exactly, changed the version.